# How to checkout a file from one branch to another in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

How to checkout a single file from one branch to another in Mercurial?

Basically I want to copy a single file from a branch `experimental` to another branch `production`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can show any file at any revision with `hg cat -r experimental filename`. But this kind of behavior looks like a debugging patch, in which case I would consider `transplant`ing (cherry-picking in other DVCS).

`hg revert -r experimental filename` could do it, not tested.

Comment: Using `transplant` avoids merge problems later.

Answer (score 2):

`hg revert` as suggested by @shellholic will indeed create a file from one branch in another branch. However the file will look as freshly added in history. Its actual history is not shown in the target branch.

I find grafting a better alternative.

Let's assume you have 2 branches, and you have created and worked on file f2.txt in the side branch. You were also working on the file f3.txt in the same branch at the same time.

[image]

1. Create another changeset in the source (side) branch, this changeset containing only the file you are interested in. If you already have such changeset, use it, no need to create a new one.
2. Update to the target branch.
3. Graft the source changeset. Mercurial will ask you if you want to use the changed version. Answer "c" (changed).

[image]

The result looks like this:

[image]

the file history is correctly preserved:

[image]

and f3.txt is *not* merged into the target branch.