# revision errors in feauture branches while converting from cvs to mercurial

Tags: mercurial, cvs

We are converting the cvs repository which has two branches (one is the MAIN and the other is the FEATURE,rest all can be ignored) into a mercurial repository.

We are using the inbuilt tool convert with the following command.

**hg convert cvs_source_dir   hg_new**

where cvs_source_dir = Updated Directory with only Feauture branch changes from CVS.
       hg_new= new name of mercurial repository   .

After converting ,the hg_new repo has all History data from CVS.
when we did an hg update it points to MAIN branch code .

And if we update it to FEATURE to get the code from FEAUTURE branch as per CVS , by using

**hg update FEAUTURE** , all the files which dont have a  revision in the FEAUTURE branch is getting deleted.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, branch FEATURE doesn't have some files that exist in branch MAIN, so when you `hg up` to branch FEATURE, these files are missing.

I think it is a feature that `hg up` brings your working directory into the status when you committed (`-c` will check the uncommitted changes), so the files that do not exist in branch FEATURE will gone.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066662/how-to-checkout-a-file-from-one-branch-to-another-in-mercurial) shows a method to get the file you want from another branch. If you have a list of files, iterate the list and get every file to your current working directory.

[Updated]
A graph to show how to make it right:

(1) your current status

```
A -- B -- C -- D (MAIN)
  \
   - E -- F -- G (FEATURE, missing files)
```

(2) step 1:

```
A -- B -- C -- D (MAIN)
  \
   - E -- F -- G (FEATURE, missing files)
    \
     -H (FEATURE, a head adding all missing files from A)
```

(3) step 2:

```
A -- B -- C -- D (MAIN)
  \
   - H - (rebase) - E' -- F' -- G' (FEATURE, missing files)
```

Comment: In the source CVS repo,some files are not modified on Feature branch .so ,these are present on MAIN and FEATURE branch as well in CVS repo.But it is not the case after migrating to mercurial? So we need the same way in Mercurial

Comment: @user1022478 CVS' history is file-based, each file has its own history. So it is possible to have one file in FEATURE and the rest in MAIN. But mercurial deals with manifest of all files, which shows the status of the working directory. My suggest is you go back to the branch point, add all files from the revision that branched off, and rebase the branch to the new revision with all files.

Comment: A graph to show how to make it right: (updated in the answer)

(1) your current status

A -- B -- C -- D (MAIN)
  \
   - E -- F -- G (FEATURE, missing files)

(2) step 1:
A -- B -- C -- D (MAIN)
  \
   - E -- F -- G (FEATURE, missing files)
   \
    -H (FEATURE, a head adding all missing files from A)

(3) step 2:
A -- B -- C -- D (MAIN)
  \
   - H - (rebase) - E' -- F' -- G' (FEATURE, missing files)